# ASDF Error when installing java get_asdf_config_value: command not found

Tags: java, jruby, asdf

Hi in a rails project we want to instal jruby as engine. So I try to install java with asdf for my rails project, and I at the end of the process I get this error:

```
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/plugins/java/bin/install: line 130: get_asdf_config_value: command not found
```

that leed to an error when installing jruby. The error there was:

```
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/plugins/java/bin/list-legacy-filenames: line 3: /Users/dmorin/.asdf/lib/utils.bash: No such file or directory
```

How could I solve this issue.

Java version adoptopenjdk-17.0.1+12

jruby version jruby-9.0.5.0

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by sourcing the `asdf.sh`-script that accompanies the `asdf`-installation:

```sh
$ source "/opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh"
```

In my case I'd installed asdf using homebrew, your installation folder might be different.

Comment: In my case, this solves the problem when my .dotfiles have problems. Specifically my PATH was being overwritten, which messed up asdf, so the second source fixed it.  Not really a fix, as the problem had nothing to do with asdf.